# Изменение текста в соседнем теге, при изменении значения input

Tags: javascript

Допустим, я решил ввести в тег `<input>` (на самой странице, а не в коде), допустим, число 7.

И теперь мне надо, чтобы когда я ввел это число, в соседнем блоке текст менялся на "abrakadabra".

А если, допустим, введу число 8, то в соседнем блоке текст меняется на "alaldlals", но прошлый текст исчезнет.

Ну и так можно продолжать до бесконечности. Как это сделать с помощью JS и HTML-тега `<input>`?

Comment: _«мне выскакивал текст»/«вылезет текст»_ - как это следует понимать?

Comment: В чем Ваш вопрос? Где Ваш код?

Comment: @yar85, да вроде всё понятно в вопросе: просто в блоке при изменении значения инпута менять текст. Если бы мне надо было добрать немного баллов до 200, я бы ответил. А раз уже набрал, то лень.

Comment: @Qwertiy, С тем же успехом можно предположить что вопрос о динамическом изменении текста в диалоговых окнах `alert` или `confirm` (они, в отличие от html-элементов, "выскакивают" и "вылезают"), и тогда это кардинально меняет суть (= невозможно, т.к. диалоги модальны). Да и вообще, подобные формулировки снижают качество вопроса... и без того печальное :)

Comment: Я не совсем смог точно выразить свой вопрос. Просто, если ввел в `input` слово help, то справа (наверху, внизу, слева, неважно, но не `alert` и т.д.) появляется текст juliHio (любой текст можно), а если ввел слово one, то прошлый текст исчезает и появляется текст juSJFj (любой можно)

Comment: @Володимер, Стоит отредактировать вопрос, внятно написав что текст должен меняться в элементе рядом с `<input>`. Это могут сделать за тебя и другие участники (которым не лень) - но пока этого не сделано, ты собираешь минусы... В данном случае я не минусил, просто объясняю из-за чего так получается и что делать (более подробно написано в справке). Еще, когда не получается подобрать слова - можно вставить в вопрос код своей попытки решения, с указанием желаемого результата.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я думаю это то, чего хотел автор вопроса.

В блоке меняется текст, в зависимости от введенного значения в input.

Сделано по примеру из ответа выше.

```js
var inp = document.getElementById('inp'),
    block = document.getElementById('block');

inp.addEventListener('input', function() {
  switch (this.value) {
  case '1':
    block.innerHTML = 'bra1';
    break;
  case '2':
    block.innerHTML = 'bra2';
    break;
  default:
    block.innerHTML = 'default text';
    break;
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inp">
<div id="block">...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Я надеюсь я все правильно понял... подсказываю только из-за того что код за минуту пишется. Вам нужно писать более полные вопросы.

```js
var inp = document.getElementById('inp');

inp.addEventListener('input', function() {
  switch (this.value) {
  case '1':
    inp.value = 'bra1';
    break;
  case '2':
    inp.value = 'bra2';
    break;
  default:
    inp.value = inp.value;
    break;
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="inp" />
```

Comment: Думаю, текст надо было не в сам инпут выводить.

Comment: И использовать `oninput` плохо. `addEventListener` же.

Comment: @Qwertiy я показал пример...вопрос тоже не ахти был. И не совсем то и понятно что в итоге хотел получить автор.